# TransformManyBlock, will returning empty IEnumerables need to be explicitly handled in order to not have them retained in memory?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I implemented a `TransformManyBlock<Tin,Tout>` and I wonder when I return an empty `IEnumerable` within the block will that empty `IEnumerable` be retained anywhere in the system or will it be garbage collected or discarded for me? Obviously I would need to handle such `IEnumerable` myself if I instead used a `TransformBlock` but I wonder whether this is already handled by the library for `TransformManyBlock`.

I guess what I like to know is whether TPL will handle the disposing of that empty IEnumerable for me or whether I need to handle it myself.

Comment: The title of your question says you return `null` values, the question itself talks about empty enumerables. This is not the same, so which one are you actually asking about? Furthermore, what does handling a return value with "staying in memory" to do?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, I updated the question. My question explicitly asks whether TPL will handle the disposing of that IEnumerable for me or whether I need to handle it myself. But let me make it clearer. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IEnumerable<T>` doesn't implement `IDisposable` and most - if not all - standard implementations of `IEnumerable<T>` don't implement `IDisposable` either. So the TPL doesn't dispose it for you if you actually return an instance of a collection that needs disposing.
But this really should never be the case if you want to return an empty enumerable, because in that case you could just return `Enumerable.Empty<T>()` or `new T[0]`.

Actually, I think you are confusing "disposing" and "garbage collection".
The empty enumerable will be available for garbage collection as soon as there are no more references pointing to it.

So, to sum it up: You don't have to worry about that, except when you want to return a very exotic enumerable implementation.

Comment: I am not sure we talk about the same thing here but this is a very specific TPL Dataflow question, quite unrelated to `IEnumerable` and `IDisposable`. `TransformManyBlock` has a specific features in which empty `IEnumerable` returned within the block are not passed on to any linked data blocks downstream. My question pertains to whether such empty `IEnumerable` are kept anywhere or whether they are "discarded" by the library for me. For example, in TPL Dataflow if I applied a filter to a tpl dataflow block then I would need to handle  such filtered results myself.

Comment: @Freddy: That would make the filter useless, wouldn't it? But maybe you can add a concrete example?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194782.aspx. Items that do not pass the filter are not automatically discarded but retained and need to be handled. Though I like to get back to `TransformManyBlock` because the concept is slightly different than filter in `TransformBlock`.

Comment: @Freddy But there is nothing special about empty enumerables here. Enumerable with items is also not kept anywhere, only its items are.

Comment: @svick, sorry but I do not understand. So, in TransformManyBlock, the items that are not passed to down-stream blocks, what happens to such items?

Comment: @Freddy Your delegate returns an enumerable. Each item from that enumerable is passed down, but the enumerable itself isn't. And it's also not kept anywhere, so it will be GCed.

Comment: @svick and Daniel, thanks for the explanation and apologies for the mixup in terminology. It is clear now.